Dask PerformanceWarning: Falling back on a non-pyarrow code path which may decrease performance
I need home help handling the new "PerformanceWarning: Falling back on a non-pyarrow code path which may decrease performance" reported by dask when running operations over some no pyarrow dtypes.
As far as I´ve read, pyarrow dtypes have better performance and lower memory consumptions! (that's great!), but I am struggling to understand how do I convert my parquet/pandas dataframe to arrow types before running my operations!
sample dataframe
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dataframe = pd.DataFrame({
    'status' :  ['pending', 'pending','pending', 'canceled','canceled','canceled', 'confirmed', 'confirmed','confirmed'],
    'clientId' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'A', 'B','C'],
    'partner' :  ['A', np.nan,'C', 'A',np.nan,'C', 'A', np.nan,'C'],
    'product' : ['afiliates', 'pre-paid', 'giftcard','afiliates', 'pre-paid', 'giftcard','afiliates', 'pre-paid', 'giftcard'],
    'brand' : ['brand_1', 'brand_2', 'brand_3','brand_1', 'brand_2', 'brand_3','brand_1', 'brand_3', 'brand_3'],
    'gmv' : [100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100]})

dataframe = dataframe.astype({'clientId':'string','partner':'string','status':'string','product':'string', 'brand':'string'})
dataframe = dd.from_pandas(dataframe, npartitions = 1)

Now I run the str replace operation
dataframe['brand_test'] = dataframe['brand']
dataframe['brand_test'] = dataframe['brand_test'].str.replace('brand_1', 'PlayStation', case=False, regex = False)

and I get this warning for every single row in my DF.
c:\Users\F3164582\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\dask_expr\_accessor.py:102: PerformanceWarning: Falling back on a non-pyarrow code path which may decrease performance.
  out = getattr(getattr(obj, accessor, obj), attr)(*args, **kwargs)

I´ve tryed to convert the datatype before running the operation, but does not work
dataframe['brand_test'] = dataframe.astype({'brand_test' : 'string[pyarrow]'})
TypeError: Column assignment doesn't support type <class 'dask_expr._collection.DataFrame'>

1) If I want, how do I silence this warning?
2) How do I "solve" this? Could I change the datatype to pyarrow string before the replace operation?
3) If pyarrow dtypes are so much better, how do I convert my hole dataframe to equivalent pyarrow datatype? Why does pandas/dask just does not convert it automatically?
Thanks in advance!

I'm able to reproduce your warning, and I'm not sure what is causing it because even disabling dask-expr or PyArrow support still gives it. However, I get this warning only once during the computation, not for every row.

You should consider this approach:
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import warnings

dataframe = pd.DataFrame({
    'status': ['pending', 'pending', 'pending', 'canceled', 'canceled', 'canceled', 'confirmed', 'confirmed', 'confirmed'],
    'clientId': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    'partner': ['A', np.nan, 'C', 'A', np.nan, 'C', 'A', np.nan, 'C'],
    'product': ['afiliates', 'pre-paid', 'giftcard', 'afiliates', 'pre-paid', 'giftcard', 'afiliates', 'pre-paid', 'giftcard'],
    'brand': ['brand_1', 'brand_2', 'brand_3', 'brand_1', 'brand_2', 'brand_3', 'brand_1', 'brand_3', 'brand_3'],
    'gmv': [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
})

dataframe = dataframe.convert_dtypes(dtype_backend='pyarrow')

dataframe = dataframe.astype({
    'status': 'string',
    'clientId': 'string',
    'partner': 'string',
    'product': 'string',
    'brand': 'string'
})

dask_dataframe = dd.from_pandas(dataframe, npartitions=1)

dask_dataframe['brand_test'] = dask_dataframe['brand'].str.replace('brand_1', 'PlayStation', case=False, regex=False)
result = dask_dataframe.compute()
result = result.convert_dtypes(dtype_backend='pyarrow')

print(result)

# Silencing the warning
#warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="Falling back on a non-pyarrow code path which may decrease performance")

I have put the silencing of warning as commented as I didn't need it. You can uncomment if you need.
      status clientId partner    product    brand  gmv   brand_test
0    pending        A       A  afiliates  brand_1  100  PlayStation
1    pending        B    <NA>   pre-paid  brand_2  100      brand_2
2    pending        C       C   giftcard  brand_3  100      brand_3
3   canceled        A       A  afiliates  brand_1  100  PlayStation
4   canceled        D    <NA>   pre-paid  brand_2  100      brand_2
5   canceled        C       C   giftcard  brand_3  100      brand_3
6  confirmed        A       A  afiliates  brand_1  100  PlayStation
7  confirmed        B    <NA>   pre-paid  brand_3  100      brand_3
8  confirmed        C       C   giftcard  brand_3  100      brand_3

